# Getting the data that was sent from a webhook thru the api route in nextjs12

Tags: reactjs, next.js, webhooks

I know I'm doing something wrong or my concept is a bit of a flawed here so any help would be appreciated.

Here is my api route code:

```
import type { NextApiRequest, NextApiResponse } from "next";

export default async (req: NextApiRequest, res: NextApiResponse) => {
  if (req.method === "POST") {
    try {
      const webhookData = req.body;
      console.log(webhookData);

      if (webhookData) {
        res
          .status(200)
          .json({ message: "Webhook received successfully", webhookData });
      } else {
        res
          .status(400)
          .json({ error: "Invalid or empty data in the webhook request" });
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.error("Error handling webhook data:", error);
      res.status(500).json({ error: "Internal server error" });
    }
  } else {
    res.status(405).json({ error: "Method not allowed" });
  }
};
```

if I send a data via postman using the webhook format, i get a response from api, however I need to pass this on a component which is i'm a bit new to that

here is my component code:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";

const NotificationChecker = () => {
  const [webhookData, setWebhookData] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("Fetching webhook data...");
    async function fetchWebhookData() {
      try {
        const response = await fetch("/api/notifydeal", {
          method: "POST",
          headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
          },
        });

        if (response.ok) {
          const data = await response.json();
          setWebhookData(data.webhookData); // Set the webhookData in component state
        } else {
          console.error(
            "Failed to fetch webhook data. Status code: ",
            response.status
          );
        }
      } catch (error) {
        console.error("Error while fetching webhook data:", error);
      }
    }

    // Fetch data on component mount
    fetchWebhookData();
  }, []); // Empty dependency array ensures this runs only once when the component mounts

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Notification Checker</h1>
      {webhookData && <pre>{JSON.stringify(webhookData, null, 2)}</pre>}
    </div>
  );
};

export default NotificationChecker;
```

but the component is not notifying / logging the response whenever the request is processed.